# UEFI install only boots if selected from BIOS

Tags: boot, uefi

I have recently reinstalled Ubuntu, and now I encounter some issues which seem to be UEFI related. I have tried searching for similar problems, but found no solutions and only one with the same problem, but the topic had no answers..

### System

Asus UX32VD, Intel based system with HD4000 + Nvidia graphics.

### Problem

The system seems to freeze at "Loading inital ramdisk". It happens both in normal booth (removing quiet splash) and when trying recovery mode. Hence, nomodeset doesn't solve the problem.

### How to reproduce

Right after reinstallation the system boots fine all the time. But when I run apt-get upgrade it will fail to boot on the next boot, in both normal and recovery mode. I have resinstalled the system several times, and the same behaviour appears after the upgrade.

### Workaround

The curious thing is that if I enter the system setup (UEFI/BIOS-screen), and then select the Ubuntu UEFI boot option, the system boots every time. But if I let the system boot normally, it won't boot. The option I select manually is the same option as the one to boot automatically.

Naturally, I would like to not have to enter the setup every time I use my system. Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've run into a kernel-specific bug. Such things are not unheard-of. The closest I know of is [this bug](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156670) under discussion on the Arch Linux forum. It's been difficult to track down, but my suspicion is that the bug the Archers have found isn't the same as yours, since their bug manifests only when using the EFI stub loader, whereas you're presumably using GRUB. (Then too, if you're *not* using GRUB, you should tell us what you are using!)

My recommendation is to try another boot loader. There's a chance that it will enable you to bypass the bug, or at least select your old working kernel. [Several alternatives are available,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) but my personal preference is [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) since I maintain it and am therefore very familiar with it. The procedure is:

1. Select a boot loader.
2. Install and test your boot loader.
3. For added safety, back up the /boot/vmlinuz-{version} and /boot/initrd.img-{version} files, as well as the /lib/modules/{version} directory, where {version} is your current working kernel version.
4. Upgrade your system.

If at this point, if you can boot into your new kernel using the new boot loader, you can put it down to a GRUB bug or a GRUB/kernel incompatibility. If the new boot loader doesn't let you boot the new kernel, try using it with the old one. If that works, then it's almost certainly some variety of kernel bug, and you can just keep using the old kernel. Keep backups, though; I'm not sure about Ubuntu, but some distributions keep only a certain number of kernels around, and so will delete your working kernel after enough kernel upgrades are pushed out.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I installed rEFInd, and using it to load GRUB made things work. So there's something strange going on.

If I selected one of the kernels directly, it couldn't find /etc/fstab so nothing got mounted, but I guess that's something to do with the configuration.

Anyways, this way it now works, although it adds a slight delay, but I can live with that.

Comment: I'm glad it works in the roundabout way. It may work more directly if you create a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file. This file is normally created automatically if you install rEFInd via the Debian package, but if it's not present, try typing `sudo mkrlconf.sh` to do the job. If that gets you a `command not found` error, you'll need to track down `mkrlconf.sh` in the rEFInd package and run it from where it exists.